# What do these values / parameters in PreparedStatement mean?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, prepared-statement, dao

I'm learning how to create a data layer using JDBC with this [DAO tutorial](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html). 
However I got stuck at this point: `PreparedStatement statement = prepareStatement(connection, SQL_UPDATE, false, values);` Why is prepareStatement used this way?

I will be grateful for any explanations and suggestions.

I have looked through [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and searched for relevant examples but haven't found any explanation of such a construct. I'm familiar with expressions like this, when *prepareStatement* method is called by *connection* object:

```
Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
```

But I do not understand why PreparedStatement is implemented like in the example below:

```
public void update(User user) throws DAOException {
    if (user.getId() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("User is not created yet, the user ID is null.");
    }

    Object[] values = {
        user.getEmail(),
        user.getFirstname(),
        user.getLastname(),
        toSqlDate(user.getBirthdate()),
        user.getId()
    };

    try (
        Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = prepareStatement(connection, SQL_UPDATE, false, values);
    ) {
        int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();
        if (affectedRows == 0) {
            throw new DAOException("Updating user failed, no rows affected.");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `prepareStatement` is a user defined method right? Please post the code of that method.

Comment: @JitinKodian I also thought that it could be some user defined method. But haven't foun it here in the  [BalusC tutorial :](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is given in the tutorial, it's part of the [DAOUtil class](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html#DAOUtil):

```
public static PreparedStatement prepareStatement
    (Connection connection, String sql, boolean returnGeneratedKeys, Object... values)
        throws SQLException
{
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql,
        returnGeneratedKeys ? Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS : Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS);
    setValues(statement, values);
    return statement;
}
```

The DaoUtil prepareStatement method is used by the DaoImpl within a try-with-resources construct. The way the initialization works there doesn't permit multiple statements, each resource has to be initialized with one expression. The method groups related initialization code together so the resource-initializing code can call it.

Also this way the parameters to the PreparedStatement are given in a more declarative way while the code to set them is hidden within the utility method. The parameter-setting is very looseygoosey and error-prone (no type-checking, among other issues), what's shown is good for a concise tutorial but not the best thing to copy on real projects.

If parameter-setting code throws a SQLException then the PreparedStatement won't get returned by the method call and won't get closed. In practice this usually isn't horrible because it will happen 
only if there is an error matching up the parameters with the placeholders in the sql (meaning you have worse problems).

The important thing is that the connection and preparedstatement get closed. Otherwise you can experiment with different ways of writing this and compare the resulting code.